# Bootstrap .btn-group-justified Improperly Retains .active Class When

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a `.btn-group-justified` as a navigation element for a set of tabs.  It appears to be functioning as expected; however, when any given button within the group is clicked it acquires the `.active` class.  Now, this is fine, but the problem is that it *retains* this class even when another button is clicked.  Here is an [example page](http://zyniker13.com/html-pages/test5.html).  The three orange button groups under "Configuration" exhibit the unexpected behaviour.  I've tried everything from reworking the nesting of the various `div`'s to including a `.container` to nesting everything in `row`'s and various sized `col`'s, but have been completely unable to eradicate this behaviour.

I am aware that it would be relatively trivial to use jQuery to clear the `.active` class whenever another member of the `.btn-group-justified` is clicked, but it seems that this behaviour is unexpected and, likely, the result of an error somewhere in the code.  However, if this behaviour is the result of an error, I cannot find it.

Comment: I don't see an active class being added. "open" is added but it works fine to me.

Comment: I should have clarified, the `.active` class is being applied to the `<li>` menu items under the drop-down button (i.e., the submenu items), not the top-level buttons.

Comment: It looks like you're missing  tabindex="-1" on the links inside the dropdown for anchors. That's the only thing I see. Plus there's a closing p wraping a pre, which is an error. But that wouldn't do that. See the source for getboostrap.com/javascript/#tabs:             <li><a href="#dropdown1" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">@fat</a></li>
            <li><a href="#dropdown2" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">@mdo</a></li>

Comment: I just tried adding `tabindex="-1"` and, unfortunately, no combination of adding or leaving it off of the various elements in that button group seemed to have any effect on the `.active` class's persistence.

Comment: Yeah, this is effing weird. All your code is good. Looking at it more.

Comment: Well, I just noticed something (potentially) helpful: The the subitems on the drop-down menus work only *once*.  e.g., if you navigate to Step 2 and then attempt to navigate back to Step 1, nothing happens.  I would imagine this is related to the `.active` issue.

Comment: I have to go an eat dinner and hang with husband. Put this jsbin in your question: http://jsbin.com/oVUzunIV/3/edit?html,console,output also might want to file a bug report with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-examples. You will find an exapmle using tabs with a dropdown. Now you are using btn-groups instead of tabs.

You use `data-toggle="tab"` from the tabs javascript plugin. This plugin requires some html structure which is not the same as your current structure. Also read: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-tabs this will show you tabs also have a class `.nav-justified`.

So replace your btn-groups with something like below to fix your problem:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="myTab">
        <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown active">
          <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" id="myTabDrop1" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul aria-labelledby="myTabDrop1" role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" tabindex="-1" href="#dropdown1">@fat</a></li>
            <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" tabindex="-1" href="#dropdown2">@mdo</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
      <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade">
          <p>Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth. Cosby sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="profile" class="tab-pane fade">
          <p>Food truck fixie locavore, accusamus mcsweeney's marfa nulla single-origin coffee squid. Exercitation +1 labore velit, blog sartorial PBR leggings next level wes anderson artisan four loko farm-to-table craft beer twee. Qui photo booth letterpress, commodo enim craft beer mlkshk aliquip jean shorts ullamco ad vinyl cillum PBR. Homo nostrud organic, assumenda labore aesthetic magna delectus mollit. Keytar helvetica VHS salvia yr, vero magna velit sapiente labore stumptown. Vegan fanny pack odio cillum wes anderson 8-bit, sustainable jean shorts beard ut DIY ethical culpa terry richardson biodiesel. Art party scenester stumptown, tumblr butcher vero sint qui sapiente accusamus tattooed echo park.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="dropdown1" class="tab-pane fade active in">
          <p>Etsy mixtape wayfarers, ethical wes anderson tofu before they sold out mcsweeney's organic lomo retro fanny pack lo-fi farm-to-table readymade. Messenger bag gentrify pitchfork tattooed craft beer, iphone skateboard locavore carles etsy salvia banksy hoodie helvetica. DIY synth PBR banksy irony. Leggings gentrify squid 8-bit cred pitchfork. Williamsburg banh mi whatever gluten-free, carles pitchfork biodiesel fixie etsy retro mlkshk vice blog. Scenester cred you probably haven't heard of them, vinyl craft beer blog stumptown. Pitchfork sustainable tofu synth chambray yr.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="dropdown2" class="tab-pane fade">
          <p>Trust fund seitan letterpress, keytar raw denim keffiyeh etsy art party before they sold out master cleanse gluten-free squid scenester freegan cosby sweater. Fanny pack portland seitan DIY, art party locavore wolf cliche high life echo park Austin. Cred vinyl keffiyeh DIY salvia PBR, banh mi before they sold out farm-to-table VHS viral locavore cosby sweater. Lomo wolf viral, mustache readymade thundercats keffiyeh craft beer marfa ethical. Wolf salvia freegan, sartorial keffiyeh echo park vegan.</p>
        </div>
```